# Get row index instead of columns in csv file

Tags: csv, python-3.x, tuples

First of all, let me just say I'm *extremely* new to Python, or any sorts of programming for that matter. Also, I wasn't sure what to put as the title,sorry. So I have this csv file opened, then I stripped and split the commas, then just to check, I printed it out and it gave me like this (just some example numbers):

```
['1','2','3','4']
['5','6','7','8']
['9','10','11','12']
```

I was wondering if there is a way I could index the rows instead of columns, like if I try to print my_list[0] it would give me 
    1
    5
    9

instead of ['1','2','3','4']. My actual problem is that I need to convert the csv data into a row of tuples WITH the elements turned to integers and be able to choose any of the rows for further processing.

I'm not familiar with a lot of the modules I've seen on this site..I'd like a really basic coding help if possible.(although it is inefficient at times)

Thank you!

Comment: stranac looks right. check this out for clarification if you need some. http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/tutorial/datastructures.html. welcome to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer follows your comments for the answer provided by stranac and tries to create a `my_list` as you wanted

```
my_list = []
with open('Test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    for lines in csvfile:
        temp_lines = lines.strip().split(',')
        my_list.append(temp_lines)

print(my_list)
```

However I would suggest that you make use of csv module already available in python.
You can see a basic example [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html)

You can do something like this:

```
import csv
my_list = []
with open('Test.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in spamreader:
        my_list.append(row)
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Oh hold on, how do I get [1,2,3,4] instead of ['1','5','9']?

Comment: once you get my_list, then print(mylist[0])

Comment: my_list is basically a list of list (<<insert inception jokes here>>). SO the first element of my_list (which is accessed through my_list[0] will be a list which will hold the values [1,2,3,4]. The second element my_list[1] will be the list [5,6,7,8] and so on

Comment: I mean, I need to change all the elements of the lists into integers. *sigh* I'm asking too much.

Comment: you can modify the solution given by stranac slightly. It will look like this my_list = [[int(x) for x in row] for row in my_list]

Comment: Don't worry about asking too much. Questions are meant to be asked and the answers questioned again in StackOverflow :D

Comment: Thank you..*sniff* Okay I hope this is the last question for today (which I think not), I've got the list of list of integers, but thing is I actually needed the inside list to be a tuple lol. So like ((1,2,3)(4,5,6) etc.)) I can change the outer bracket, still trying to work on the insides.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18397/discussion-between-user1632262-and-pulimon)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a rather simple list comprehension to convert your list to a format you want(after getting the list from the csv), using `zip(*my_list)` to transpose it:

```
>>> my_list = [['1','2','3','4'],
...            ['5','6','7','8'],
...            ['9','10','11','12']]
>>> [[int(x) for x in row] for row in zip(*my_list)]
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

Comment: Hmm how do I make a nested list from the stripped/split lines? Because they're not exactly 'next' to each other if you get what I mean.

Comment: Oh, I assumed you were using the `csv` module, which would give you an object you can use like a list of lists. If you need to create the list of lists manually, you could just append each line's results to the list.

Comment: I did something like: my_list = [],for x in file_open, x = x.strip().split(','), then end_list = my_list.append(x) but it gave me 'None'. But I'll try the csv reader.

Comment: Actually, that should have been just `my_list.append(x)`, and then you would use `my_list`. `end_list` is not needed at all. But using the `csv` module is a much better and simpler method.